# BouncyCastle - To verify the signature

Tags: java, c#, bouncycastle

Requester has signed using their own private key in Java.

```java
public static String signHash(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] hash)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
    privateSignature.update(hash);
    byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
}
```

Receiver is unable to verify their signature. We are using bouncyCastle in .NET to validate.

```cs
public bool VerifySignature(AsymmetricKeyParameter pubKey, byte[] signature, byte[] msg)
{
    try
    {
        ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withRSA");
        signer.Init(false, pubKey);
        signer.BlockUpdate(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        return signer.VerifySignature(signature);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Verification failed with the error: " + exc.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String signHash(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] hash)
```

This is not how signatures work in Java, you supply the message instead of the hash, so presumably the data has been hashed twice in Java, and only once during verification using Bouncy Castle in C#.

Comment: We generate the hash from the actual message and sign it .

Comment: public static byte[] generateHash(String message)
   throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
  MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
  byte[] hash = digest.digest(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  return hash;
 }

Comment: Yes, but that's already performed by `Signature`, hence the hash name inside the name of the signature. You *configure* the signature function with a specific hash algorithm to hash the data *inside the instance of `Signature`*. You only need to encode your message to binary prior.

Comment: @ArunaGiriNathan Or rephrased: in Java your code is signing the hash of the hash of the message (sign(hash(hash(message)))), and in C# your code is verifying the signature of the hash of the message (sign(hash(message))). Either you need to change your Java code to sign the hash of the message, or you need to change your C# code to verify the signature of the hash of the hash of the message.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark. I'm not sure how to change it in the .NET bountyCaste method ? Could you please help us which line to change ?

Comment: Is the same did it in Java ?                                               
         https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signhash?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: i tried use this one also , No luck.:( Can you show me where to add the line in C# ?

Comment: Currently we don't have a [mcve] so it's pretty hard to tell what could be wrong otherwise. Badly configured keys, etc. What you could do is to hex or base 64 encode the input to the signature generation and verification operations and check if it is identical in both cases. Very often it is as simple as changing the character encoding of the message input.